# Differential equations of multiple input circuit

Tags: lti-system

I am trying to find the linear differential equation(s) that describe this electrical circuit. When both resistances are equal, I have found the expression:

[image: (C_1+2C_2)R\frac{du_{12}}{dt}=u_{i1}-u_{i2}-u_{12}]

With [image: u_{12}=u_1-u_2]

But how to do it with different resistances (but still both C1 equal)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJd1iR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

After laborious calculations, I obtained these results which, however, I have not yet verified:

[image]